# Asp with Jquery wont work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mono

i am try to write with Mono a little Asp site including JQuery.
If i add a normal Html element like this:

```
<input name="test" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30"></input>
```

it works very well, but if i add a asp Element like this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

i get always this exception in firefox (Firebug):

> 500 Internal Server Error828ms

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Comment: Controls marked with `runat="server"` require an `ID` attribute as well. Have you tried adding an `ID="TextBox1"` to your `runat="server"` controls?

Comment: yes, the problem i have found, is the 'runat="server"' attribut, without this, it works. But i need it for the C# connection.

Comment: Can you post the jQuery code that is causing the error (the full function)?